# R - where should I place RDA file - /R, /data, /inst/extdata?

Tags: r, package

According to the "Writing R Extensions" manual, there are three directories where RDA files can be placed: `/R`, `/data`, `/inst/extdata`

Its really hard to decipher the best-practice from the manual.  Could someone comment on when/why to place RDA files in each of these three directories.

Here's the specific cases I'm solving for:
I have 1 RDA file that will be used in function examples as well as in my test_that tests (which all live in inst/tests)

Comment: no definitive answer from me - but you could go take a gander at some of your favorite packages and see where they put their RDA files to gain some inspiration

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Starting with *the* manual for package writing strikes me as a good approach. The `data/` directory looks like a good bet to me.  As I recall, `inst/extdata` was suggested for non-R data sets or some such.

The general rule still is that all directories below `inst/` will be copied as-is; the `data/` directory may be transformed. The manual will have details.  So if you wanted it just for regression tests, you could use `inst/testData` (say) and, once the package is installed, you can use `system.file("testData", package="yourPackageNameHere")` to compute it.